# No /etc/init.d/arangod found after debian installation (3.3.22)

Tags: arangodb

I just installed (in silent mode) Arango 3.3.22 on my debian 9 distrib. After a successful installation with apt-get, I am unable to start arango as no arangod script is found in /etc/init.d

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Install log:

```
root@36e94c84086b:/# apt-get install arangodb3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  arangodb3
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 34.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 301 MB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  arangodb3
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Get:1 https://download.arangodb.com/arangodb33/Debian_9.0  arangodb3 3.3.22 [34.6 MB]
Fetched 34.6 MB in 29s (1174 kB/s)
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Selecting previously unselected package arangodb3.
(Reading database ... 21516 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../arangodb3_3.3.22_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking arangodb3 (3.3.22) ...
Setting up arangodb3 (3.3.22) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
/usr/sbin/policy-rc.d returned 101, not running 'is-active arangodb3.service'
/usr/sbin/policy-rc.d returned 101, not running 'stop arangodb3.service'
2019-04-05T10:26:20Z [557] INFO {syscall} file-descriptors (nofiles) hard limit is 1048576, soft limit is 1048576
2019-04-05T10:26:20Z [557] INFO {startup} Server will now shutdown due to upgrade, database init or admin restoration.
Database files are up-to-date.
root@36e94c84086b:/# /etc/init.d/
hwclock.sh  procps      x11-common
```

Comment: I solved this by going back to Debian 8 and following instructions from http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/how-to-install-oracle-java-8-in-debian.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by going back to Debian 8 and following instructions from webupd8.org/2014/03/how-to-install-oracle-java-8-in-debian.html

Comment: The link does not work and downgrading the distribution just sounds wrong. There must be some problem with the arangodb package or your setup. I accept that this is a valid work around for you, but I would rather understand and fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use `systemctrl <action> arangodb3.service` to manipulate the service where `<action>` is in `start`, `stop`, `status`, `restart`.

Comment: Thank you but systemctl start arangodb3.service fails with error : "Unknown unit". It seems that no init script are installed (no init.d nor systemctl stuff)...

Comment: Hi, can you verify with `dpkg -l | grep arango` that the arangodb package is installed. It must be marked with `ii` to be installed.Even if it is installed you could try to install `apt-utils` and reinstall arangodb.

Comment: And finally you might ask your admin about `/usr/sbin/policy-rc.d`. To me it looks like the exit status of that script denies the invocation of the service.